# Python multithreading service

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, service

I'm trying to create windows service on python with several threads.
I wrote the code that **works as I need**, but I can't understand how it breaks the threads!
Why `break` in `while` loop break the threads which are not in the `while` loop?

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import threading
from classifier import clf, refit

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop) 

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,'')) 
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=clf)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=refit)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        while True:        
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 100)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service process terminates when `SvcDoRun` returns. That brings the threads down with the rest of the process. If you wish your threads to continue to execute then you must keep the process alive. In other words don't return from `SvcDoRun`.

Comment: But if I need that threads work continuously and terminates only when the service is stopped this is the right way?

Comment: Is what the right way? Didn't I answer your question which was why the threads stopped.

Comment: Incidentally this is the opposite behavior of standard python, which I think is where the OP's confusion is coming from. If you just called `SvcDoRun` directly, the python process wouldn't exit, because the threads are non-daemonic. (Assuming that the base class isn't calling that method from a daemonic thread.) The threads are deliberately killed as part of the service termination, not from the ordinary operation of the interpreter.